# Heat Kernel and Convex sets

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let  G be the Heat Kernel

$G(t,x)=[4\pi t]^{-\frac{N}{2}}e^{-|x|^{2}/(4t)}$

$(t>0)$

$K \subset  \mathbb C^d$

Let $K$ be a closed convex set and $K'=\left\{u\in C :u(x) \in K \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R^n \right\} $

($C:$ continuous functions in $\mathbb R^n$)

if $u_0 \in K'$ then is it true that $u(t)=G(t)*u_0 \in K'$?

Comment: I edited the definition of $K'$ so that the question makes sense to me. Please check it has the intended meaning. The answer is yes, with this edit, since $u(t)$ is a weighted average of the values of $u_0$. A hint to prove this: Since $K\subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed and convex, and $u_0 \in K'$, the entire interval $[\inf u_0,\sup u_0]$ is contained in $K$.

Comment: You are right @Jeff, it is that way. Thanks.